# Feature processing for kNN

Tags: machine-learning, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution, k-nearest-neighbour, data-preprocessing

I have this feature for which the distribution looks like:
[image]

I am curious as to what kind of feature processing I can do (and to similar other features) which makes it amenable for kNN.

Here's what I tried:

In an attempt to convert the feature from exponential (here) to normal distribution, I did the ecdf = exponential.CDF(X) and then normal.inverseCDF(ecdf). But the resulting distribution is also exponential in nature.

In terms of feature pre-processing, what else can I do?

Comment: Are you sure that the data is valid? For instance that the 0 values don't mean 'missing value', or has been entered in a different unit (ex millimeters instead of meters).